# Azure Blob API hanging when running .NET Core in a Docker container

Tags: c#, .net, azure, containers, blob

Same code below, when running as a Windows console app, works fine (Log 1 and Log 2 are both hit).

But when running this code in a container (with VS debugger attached, Linux via WLS). The code `GetPropertiesAsync()` is hanging, Log 2 never hit. No exception neither (Log 3 not hit).

Have tried running this code in a new .NET 6.0 WorkerService project.

Azure.Storage.Blobs is V12.6, container's network connection is working.

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;

namespace WorkerService1
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var storageAccount = new BlobServiceClient("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[ACCOUNTNAME];AccountKey=[ACCOUNTKEY];EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");

                var container = storageAccount.GetBlobContainerClient("blobcontainer1");

                var blob = container.GetBlobClient("/afile.txt");

                try
                {
                    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Log 1");

                    var properties = await blob.GetPropertiesAsync();

                    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Log 2");
                }
                finally
                {
                    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Log 3");
                }

                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My "feeling" is, if I reboot machine, it probably will work. Because this part of code worked before.  Will do experiment and update below.
But even if it works after reboot, it feel very strange that why that API would stuck? It should throw an exception (even timeout exception) if anything wrong rather than hanging.

**Update**: Yes, after reboot, it works.

Still.... it's strange.

Comment: Do you want to start a root folder or relative to the executable?  Try adding a period : var blob = container.GetBlobClient("./afile.txt");

Comment: Might be networking issue. Would need to look at the implementation but my guess it that ```container.GetBlobClient("/afile.txt");``` does not actually do much of anything other than creating an object for you to talk to the blob. I sometimes have issues on WSL where I cannot push a commit or similar that "fixes" itself too either after restarting WSL or closing vscode that accesses WSL files and then magically it starts working again. How long did you wait? Timeouts take like half a minute or a minute to occur.

Comment: hi @jdweng, It's inrelevant to what to do with blob.  Any activity results the same.

Comment: @Max, shouldn't it throw timeout exception if it's network issue?

Comment: Thats why I ask how long you waited. It sure won´t if you are impatient.

Comment: Ahhh. It's almost "infinite".  "Only" waited for 20 minutes, but even that's a bit too long.

Comment: Yeah... usually more like a minute at most. Then I don´t know either tbh. Code looks fine.